# Imagick: EPS to JPG

Tags: php, imagick

I have an eps. I want to make an jpg out of it. I tried everything, but the quality is too bad.
I think imagick takes the original size of the file, makes an jpg, and then makes it bigger without any compression. The problem is, the generated image of the eps is in bad quality, and the bigger image is totally bad.
Here are some configurations I tried:

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($imagePath);
$imagick->flattenImages();
$imagick->resizeImage(1024, 0, \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$imagick->setImageResolution(300, 300);
$imagick->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$imagick->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$imagick->setCompressionQuality(100);
$imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$imagick->writeImage($new_imagePath);
```

Can anyone help me with this? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the image density/resolution **before** you read the Encapsulated PostScript file.

```php
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(100); // or 300
$imagick->readImage($imagePath);
```

Also note that, by nature, EPS is a vector format, and JPEG is a lossy raster format. Rendering at a low dpi, and resizing up to a given size will *always* result in poor quality. Either render at a high-dpi & downsample to a given size, or render at expected size & omit any resizing.

Comment: No, unfortuanetly it doesnt make any difference